# nHibernate QueryOver Inheritance

Tags: nhibernate, linq-to-nhibernate, nhibernate-criteria, queryover

I have something like this :

```
    public class User
    {
       /* some properties */
       public virtual int Id { get; set; }
       public abstract string LastName { get; }

    }
    public class Student 
    {
       public virtual int Id { get; set; }
       public virtual string LastName{ get; set; }
    }

    public class StudentUser : User
    {
       public virtual Student Student { set; get; }

        public override string LastName 
        {
            get { return Student.LastName; }
        }
    }

    public class foo
    {
         public virtual int Id { get; set; }

         public virtual IList<User> Users { get; set; }
    }


 1. I would like to do the following using QueryOver :
   var query = session.QueryOver<foo>();
       User User = null;

//case 1: This is not working
       query.JoinAlias(x=> x.Users , () => User )
                 .Where(() => ((StudentUser)User).Student.LastName == "smith" );

//case 2: Also This is not working
       query.JoinAlias(x=> x.Users , () => User )
                 .Where(() => ((StudentUser)User).LastName == "smith" );

//case 3: This is working
       query.JoinAlias(x=> x.Users , () => User )
                 .Where(() => ((StudentUser)User).Id == 123 );
```

When I use `query.JoinAlias(x=> x.Users , () => User )` more than one time, I get this exception `An item with the same key has already been added`.

Also I get this exception : could not resolve property: Student.LastName of: Entities.User in case 1 and case 2

But it is working with the Id property (case 3)

It might be look like :

```
SELECT        *
FROM         Foo INNER JOIN
                      Users ON Foo.Id = Users.FooId_FK INNER JOIN
                      Students ON Users.StudentId_FK = Students.Id
where Students.LastName = 'smith'
```

How can I get the LastName property value?

Comment: Would a readonly view of StudentUser and a writeable one ok? Are all Students and the like Users or not?

Comment: Can you show your mappings?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I *think* this should work:

```
session.QueryOver<foo>()
    .JoinQueryOver(f => f.Users)
    .JoinQueryOver(u => ((StudentUser)u).Student)
        .Where(st => st.LastName == "smith")
```

Or keeping with `JoinAlias`:

```
User userAlias = null;
Student studentAlias = null;

session.QueryOver<foo>()
    .JoinAlias(f => f.Users, () => userAlias)
    .JoinAlias(() => ((StudentUser)userAlias).Student, () => studentAlias)
        .Where(() => studentAlias.LastName == "smith")
```

Comment: Wow, this is really wokring with QueryOver? Cool! ;) Expression parser with casting... have to love NHibernate...

Comment: @RadimKöhler: Yep, you can do this with selects and I'm 90% sure you can do it with joins too... Without the OP's mappings its hard to test and know for sure

Comment: Thank you @AndrewWhitaker ,it works just perfect .. another question, when i use the same join multiple times (.JoinAlias(f => f.Users, () => userAlias)), i get this exception "An item with the same key has already been added" 

what should i do ?

Comment: @NH89: Unfortunately that's a bug/missing feature in QueryOver and criteria: you casn't join to the same table multiple times in a single query.

Comment: can i check if i already joined that table before, as in criteria there is something like get Critera by alias, can this be applied here too ?

Comment: @NH89: The best I've come up with is to create a boolean value that keeps track of whether I've done the join or not. This isn't elegant at all, but it works.

Comment: Actually, i resolve it by doing this : 
IQueryOver<foo,User> Join = null;

check if(join == null ), if so do this :
Join = query.JoinQueryOver(f => f.Users);


Hope it's helpfull. :)